# matplotlib autoscale with respect to a specific plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code that plots two graphs. By default matplotlib autoscales current axis to fit the bigger plot, so if I have a code like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 200)
f = np.exp(-x)
g = np.exp(-x-2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, f)
ax.plot(x, g)
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
```

It will show

[image: exp]

I'd like a way to tell matplotlib which one of the plots to use for the autoscaling. E.g. I could manually set limits like

```
ax.set_ylim(g.min(), g.max())
```

and get my desired plot. I guess though that the default code path for autoscaling is slightly more complicated than just setting the limits like this. So is there a way to keep the autoscaling while selecting which plot to use as a reference?

[image: exp2]